# selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page

Tags: python, selenium

```
driver.get("https://www.zacks.com/")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search-q']")
```

i am trying to find search box on zacks website with selenium but I am getting StaleElementReferenceException

Comment: What are you trying to do on that element when you receive that error ?

Comment: trying to send a stock symbol and click search

Comment: Are you try to select any of the suggestion or just want to type in stock symbol and press enter ?

Comment: @SariqShaikh yes just enter symbol and press enter it should work like this

Comment: Than just open the url directly by appending the the stock symbol like this driver.get(‘https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/IBM’)  don’t bother about locating element and typing in in the search box. IBM is the term you will add dynamically to the url.

Comment: @SariqShaikh well I tried that but what is important for me is to get stock rating later which is also showing same error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this error is simply, the element has been removed from the DOM. There are several reasons for this:

- The page itself is destroying/recreating the element on the fly, maybe even rapidly.
- Parts of the page have been updated (replaced), but you're still having and old reference.
- You navigate to a new page but holding an old reference.

To avoid this, try to keep the element reference as short as possible. If the content is rapidly changing, make the operation directly without the round trip to the client, via javascript:

```
driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('serach-q').click();");
```

Comment: I need to get the rating of the stock when i send the symbol. do you know how?

Comment: I do not know your workflow and your goal. Automated testing? Or just extracting? If latter, then avoid using the search box (which pops up a dynamic dropdown), instead visit the stock page directly, for example, `https://www.zacks.com/stock/quote/DOW` (DOW). From there, you can extract the information of interest.

Comment: yes I already did that I went to the website directly with quote, but I cant grab the rating, element not present it says

Comment: I just tried on the browser console: `document.getElementsByClassName("rank_view")[0].innerHTML` and get: `5-Strong Sell`. So `sell_signal = driver.executeScript("document.getElementsByClassName("rank_view")[0].innerHTML");` should work?

Comment: I am working with python in intellij do you think you know how to workaround that?Thank you

Comment: work around what? Did you tried my command? Here's a small sample how to execute javascript with phyton/selenium: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-execute-javascript/

Comment: The javascript approach mentioned by @Arakis should be your best bet, try it once and update the question if you have any problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to find while the page and this exact search box are loading. Try to implement wait mechanism for this element, smth like that:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
```